# YouTube Analytics API Access Now Forbidden

Tags: youtube-analytics-api

I have a few reports using the YouTube Analytics API in a Google Spreadsheet. I have made no changes recently.

These reports do have a trigger that run daily. On 1/10. they stopped working.

Usage Report: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2rUL.png

I see at least four similar issues here. I am posting this in hopes to raise more awareness in case there is an bigger issue at hand, than some user error I cannot ID.

Spreadsheet reports the following error:

[16-01-20 08:55:01:935 PST] Execution failed: Forbidden (line 45, file "yt-sources") [0.83 seconds total runtime]

Line 45 is:

var analyticsResponse = YouTubeAnalytics.Reports.query(

I have the same issue across two accounts (using different YouTube accounts).

I also recreated them, and tried the sample report (https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/code_samples/apps-script#export_youtube_analytics_data_to_google_sheets), which my reports are based off of.

I am still able to pull data via the Analytics API Explorer.